# Does Stack Overflow use Gridview or Listview?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, technology

Does Stack Overflow use Gridview or Listview for listing its questions and answers?

Comment: Why are people voting to close this.  It is a valid programming question, hmm maybe someone wants to develop similiar functionality so they want to know what type of control this is.  People stop being so click happy...this site being run by the users seems to be getting worse then better.

Comment: First rule of Stackoverflow.  You do not talk about stackoverflow.

Comment: @JonH - IMHO Sarah 'wonders'. The question, as it is now, does not relate to a programming concept. And, it will be better answered by the guys at meta.stackoverflow.com. Although, if she had asked, why SO uses alphaview instead of betaview, it would have been better suited. i am just saying ...

Answer (score 4):

My guess is, it's simply a for loop written in-line.

```
    <% foreach (Question q in (IEnumerable)ViewData["Questions"]) { %>

    <h2>
        <%= q.Title%>
    </h2>

<% } %>
```

For instance...

Comment: Which looks way cleaner than webform gunk.

Answer (score 3):

Stackoverflow is built using ASP.NET MVC, not webforms.  So, they most likely just loop through the questions on the page and build the html.